# Apple shortcuts in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, gnome, hotkeys

I switch between a Mac and Ubuntu often. On my Ubuntu box, I use an Apple Aluminum keyboard.

I'm interested in Apple's "command" key:  **⌘**.  
(I'm not concerned about the hardware control keys.)

- <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> opens a browser tab
- <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for copy/paste, *especially* in a terminal window
- <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> maintains the same meaning in terminal (abort)

Just switching the control & command keys in Ubuntu would almost get me there, except for the special behavior of the keys a terminal (Terminal is my most frequently used app.)

Has it been done?

edit: using Gnome, not KDE

Answer (score 0):

I had a look a a similar problem a while ago.

The problem was trying to make <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> send something different than <kbd>Command</kbd>+(not C/X/V).

Maybe [Autokey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/) (Linux/Python version) can help?

For Gnome Terminal, mapping:

- Command+C = Ctrl+Ins
- Command+V = Shift+Ins
- Command+X = Ctrl+Del

should be the easiest option, or you can can go to Edit->Keyboard Shortcuts if you need to use something else.