# Gnome 3 copy/paste with a Mac keyboard

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to use a Mac keyboard in Linux with Gnome 3. What I essentially want is to have <kbd>Cmd</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys behave like in Mac: do all copy/cut/paste, window switch and etc. using <kbd>Cmd</kbd> key *but* in Terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and friends to do their normal job.

I suppose that it can be accomplished if I software-swap somehow <kbd>Cmd</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys and put exceptions for Terminal app. But so far Google didn't show me the true & ultimate way of doing that.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/247993/apple-shortcuts-in-ubuntu?rq=1